# Spatial4j - Create circle using centroid and radius in miles

Tags: java, spatial

Using Spatial4j, I want to create a circle using a centroid and radius specified in miles (or kilometers).  The Javadoc says "The units of "distance" should be the same as x & y." which I am confused by.

I understood x and y (lat, lon) to be in degrees and I don't know how to express the radius in degrees.  I want to express it in miles, so I imagine I need to convert miles to degrees, however I also know the conversion is different based on where the centroid is on the surface of the planet.

Is there a way within Spatial4j to easily handle this conversion so I can express the radius in miles and create an accurate circle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DistanceUtils](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/locationtech/spatial4j/master/src/main/java/org/locationtech/spatial4j/distance/DistanceUtils.java) class has the conversion methods you seek, Brooks:

> public static double calcBoxByDistFromPt_deltaLonDEG(double lat, double lon, double distDEG)

Should sort you, hope that helps!

Comment: The Javadoc for that method says "The delta longitude of a point-distance. In other words, half the width of the bounding box of a circle."  Parameters for that method are lat, lon and distance in degrees.  I'm not clear on how to get from distance in miles to distance in degrees, otherwise I would just create the circle with distance in degrees to begin with, right?

Comment: Look at the other methods in the DistanceUtils class, perhaps one of those may be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

From meters:

```
static double metersToDistanceDeg(int meters) {
    return (1.0 * meters / (1000 * DistanceUtils.DEG_TO_KM));
}
```

Or if you have miles:

```
static double milesToDistanceDeg(int miles) {
    return (DistanceUtils.MILES_TO_KM * miles / DistanceUtils.DEG_TO_KM);
}
```